# Blazor WebAssembly exception does not show ErrorContent

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

The contents of the `ErrorContent` component are not rendered when I throw an exception in a method in the `ChildContent` of an `ErrorBoundary` component.

I've created a new Blazor WebAssembly project in .NET 6 (`dotnet --version` => 6.0.401) with `dotnet new blazorwasm -o BlazorWasmDemo`.

I modified `Counter.razor` to throw in the `IncrementCount` method if the `currentCount` exceeds 2:

```
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>@pageTitle</PageTitle>

<h1>@pageTitle</h1>
<ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildContent>
        <p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
    </ChildContent>
    <ErrorContent>
        <p>Aw snap!</p>
    </ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>

@code {
    private string pageTitle = "Counter v1.1";
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        if (currentCount > 2)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Counter cannot be more than 2.");
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the framework to show my content rather than the default yellow bar at the bottom (`#blazor-error-ui` defined in `wwwroot\index.html`) but it's as if I've made no change. (I've modified the page title and header to verify that I am loading the modified page.)

What am I missing?

Comment: How do I get the Blazor version @HenkHolterman ?

Comment: The only versions I have in the csproj file are `TargetFramework` (net6.0), and 6.0.7 for the WebAssembly package references.

Comment: It works if I move the `ErrorBoundary` to `mainLayout.razor` and use it to wrap `@Body`. I guess this comes down to "You're holding it wrong"?